# How to replace one component to another in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have three component in screen with same size but different static data.

I want to replace the every 5 seconds on the screen in the same area(display position is fix). For ex. I have `<FeedbackComp1>`, `<FeedbackComp2>` and `<FeedbackComp3>`. So, I want display and replace the component every 5 seconds.

Display: first time render the screen display the `<FeedbackComp1>` and then replace the place `<FeedbackComp2>` and then `<FeedbackComp3>` and then `<FeedbackComp1>` so on.

If possible this functionality in array map() function so I also ready for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

// placeholders for your actual components.
const FeedbackComp1 = () => <></>
const FeedbackComp2 = () => <></>
const FeedbackComp3 = () => <></>

const MyComponentSwitcher = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const components = [<FeedbackComp1/>, <FeedbackComp2/>, <FeedbackComp3/>]


  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex(currentIndex => (currentIndex + 1) % components.length)
    }, 5000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return components[index]
}
```

Short explanation:

- The `index` state-variable holds the index we're currently at.
- The `components` array holds the components you want to switch between.
- The `useEffect` initializes an interval of 5000 ms, so that every 5 seconds, it will set the index to one more than it currently is, using the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to ensure we never have an index outside the array.

  - Note that the `setIndex` doesn't take in a new value, but rather a callback. This allows us to automatically set the value to one higher than before, without having to reference the value when the component is initialized. [React reference.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)
- The `return` statement simply returns the current component.

Comment: Cool! If this works out for you, feel free to accept the answer :) Good luck!

Comment: Hey @Sebastian, This is stuck the after display second component.

Comment: If you another solution in array is also ready.

Comment: You forget the pass the dependency in useEffect(()=>{},[index]) function. Update the code and Thank You.

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that the `setIndex` now takes a callback. This is [documented in the React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: That also works, and you probably won't notice a difference, but just to explain why that works: By adding the index dependency, you clear the interval and set up a new one every time the index changes, which basically means it will always just run once before it re-initializes. My new proposed solution just initializes the `useEffect` once, and I believe it should work quite well.

Comment: Yes, are you right. I also change the code.